# Most efficient way for finding non-matching values in 2 lists

Tags: python

I've got a case where I have two lists of arbitrary lengths. Each value in these lists is another list of n float values.

```
a = [[0.8,0.9,1.], [0.5,2.6,2.2], [1.5,5.6], [5.8,2.3,1.9],] 

b = [[0.8,0.91,1.01], [2.5,4.6,8.8], [1.49,5.59],]
```

I want to compare values in both lists and find those values that are not within a given tolerance.

What I'm interested in is the most efficient way to achieve this in pure Python without reverting to compiled code or multi threading, and using only standard libraries. Hopefully I can learn something more in the process!

Example:

Given a tolerance of 0.001, which is a measure of the max distance between the two compared values,comparing lists a and b would return:

Matching values in a and b:

am = [[0.8,0.9,1.], [1.5,5.6],]

be = [[0.8,0.91,1.01], [1.49,5.59],]

Non-matching values:

anm = [[0.5,2.6,2.2], [5.8,2.3,1.9],]

bnm = [[2.5,4.6,8.8],]

We can also expect that there would be no duplicates. Does that help?

Comment: Are you bound to lists, or can you use numpy arrays?

Comment: @Raoul `using only standard libraries`

Comment: What's an example of the output you expect given a tolerance?

Comment: I think you should clarify what you mean by "find those values that are not within a given tolerance”.

Comment: what are you comparing exactly?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far (so we can get an idea of what you're attempting to do..?)

Comment: I came up with [this](https://gist.github.com/prologic/ec2ed327030d445bfe92); it's the opposite of what the OP wants; but can easily be inverted.

Comment: Yeah, sorry was sleeping. I'll add more detail in a second.

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension you can achive this

```
result = [ y for x in a for y in x if low<=y<=high]
```

this code will give you the values that are between `low` and `high`

Comment: Am I the only person who did not understand this?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the problem is that the OP hasn’t told us _what_ he wants. `find those values that are not within a given tolerance.` is terribly vague.

Comment: That's in the right ball-park, but not exactly what I wanted. I've updated the question to assist. Also, although what you have is very pythonic, I'm after the most efficient implementation. Not sure this is it.